# How to run a cli script in pimcore

Tags: pimcore

till Now I have been placing all my code within pimcore\cli\startup.php and it's run fine but when I'am trying in another way I getting error like 
Class 'Website\ObjectExporter' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pimcore\website\var\cli\export-objects.php on line 7
How to run code in this way

For example create an ObjectExporter.php under /website/lib/Website folder with this content:

```
<?php
namespace Website;

class ObjectExporter
{
    public function exportObjects()
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Then you can either instantiate this class in your controller action or in a CLI script. Controller actions are within /website/controllers folder and they need to be called through http: http://localhost?controller=default&action=default

Example: /website/controllers/DefaultController.php

```
<?php
class DefaultController extends Website_Controller_Action {
    public function defaultAction () {
        $this->disableViewAutoRender();

        $objectExporter = new Website\ObjectExporter();
        $objectExporter->exportObjects();
    }
}
```

(You could also add your whole code directly into action, but that would be a bit ugly solution, it of course depends)

But better and quickest way to approach such tasks is with the CLI scripts.
I like to use the /website/var/cli folder (you need to create it manually, but the  /website/var folder is excluded in .htaccess by default which makes it practical for such use cases).

Example: /website/var/cli/export-objects.php

```
<?php
$workingDirectory = getcwd();
chdir(__DIR__);
include_once("../../../pimcore/cli/startup.php");
chdir($workingDirectory);

$objectExporter = new Website\ObjectExporter();
$objectExporter->exportObjects();
```

Then just run it by issuing this command in your command line:

```
php website/var/cli/export-objects.php
```

Comment: This doesn't really fit the Q&A format of StackOverflow. 
You should ask a definitive question and feel free to answer this question yourself in the answer section then, not just put a "How To" completely in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way of creating CLI scripts in pimcore: 
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16854341

Basically it's just Symfony/Console, which is documented in here detail: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html